# Set width and height of UITextView based on the dynamic text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview, swift3

I'm building a chat application where each message are inserted into a row inside a table. Each row contains an avatar and a message. I want to set the width and height of the UITextArea as per the length of the text to put inside.

Below is the code I've used. But here, both height and width are constant (200x50)

PS: I'm a newbie to Swift and ios and I'm using Swift 3. Every code I got after searching is in objective-c or swift 2

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell  = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ChatBox1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ChatBox1


        let myTextField: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 20, width: 200.00, height: 50.00));
        cell.addSubview(myTextField)
        myTextField.isScrollEnabled = false
        myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        myTextField.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
        myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        print(myTextField.intrinsicContentSize)


        let image = UIImage(named: "agent")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        cell.addSubview(imageView)


        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try cell.sizeToFit()

Comment: Have a look at `boundingRect(with:options:attributes:context:)`, which is a method of `NSString`. You can use this method to calculate the size of the whole string, and then set the `textView` as well as the cell height accordingly

Comment: Try cell.sizeToFit() and also try inside your number of row.....  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.  This will fix your problem....

Comment: cell.sizeToFit() is not working. I tried myTextField.sizeToFit(). Is it possible to set height of table row based on this?

Comment: Is nothing to do with your texfield.check my other comment.thats the answer you were looking for....

Comment: @Joe Where should i put  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension ? inside viewdidload?

Comment: Inside your func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {      return yourArray.count }

Comment: checkout my answer...

Comment: answer updated...

Comment: I'm trying it. one min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

Answer 1:

```
   func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 

        yourTableViewName.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // Standard tableViewCell size
        yourTableViewName.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

   return yourArrayName.count } 


   And also put this code inside your Cell for incase...
   yourCell.sizeToFit()
```

Answer 2:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Comment: It could be a layout issue.check your constrains.

Answer (score 2):

This two methods are done to set Height and width of textview according to the text on chat.

You can use these. (swift 2.3)

```
var screenrect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

func GET_WIDTH(textView : UITextView , text : String)-> CGFloat
    {
        textView.text = text;
        let size = textView.bounds.size
        let newSizeWidth = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.max, height: size.height))
        // Resize the cell only when cell's size is changed
        if size.width != newSizeWidth.width
        {
            if( newSizeWidth.width > screenrect.width-120 )
            {
                textView.layer.frame.size.width = screenrect.width-120;

            }
            else if ( newSizeWidth.width < 40 )
            {
                textView.layer.frame.size.width = 40
            }
            else
            {
                textView.layer.frame.size.width = newSizeWidth.width;
            }
        }
        return textView.layer.frame.size.width + 40;
    }

    func GET_HEIGHT(textView : UITextView , text : String)-> CGFloat
    {
        textView.text = text;
        let size2 = textView.bounds.size
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size2.width, height: CGFloat.max))
        if size2.height != newSize.height
        {
            if( newSize.height < 40 )
            {
                textView.layer.frame.size.height = 40
            }
            else
            {
                textView.layer.frame.size.height = newSize.height
            }
        }
        return textView.layer.frame.size.height + 15;
    }
```

You have to call the functions of the textview like this to set height and width.

```
 let textViewRight=UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 4, 40, 40));
 textViewRight.layer.frame.size.width = GET_WIDTH(textViewRight, text: currentObject.chat_userMessage)
 textViewRight.layer.frame.size.height = GET_HEIGHT(textViewRight, text: currentObject.chat_userMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad Add this

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Just add these two lines and your problem will b solved

Answer (score 0):

Take textView height constraint and set it equal to the content size of the textView.

Alternatively, if you use autolayout you can set the content hugging and compression property to 1000. It should expand your cell according to the content.